# mysqli_query sending null for last row and column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, null

I am fetching a row in php using mysqli_query but getting one of the columns as null for the latest entry in the table. Using the following code -

```
$res = mysqli_query($this -> database -> connection, "select IPM.collected, IPM.invoice_id, IPM.invoice_payment_id, 
        zb_inv_payment_id as zb_ipi
        from expense_system.invoice_payment_mapper as IPM             
        where IPM.invoice_payment_id = 200") -> fetch_assoc();
```

In the above query `zb_inv_payment_id` always comes as null when ran using the above code, but returns fine when using phpmyadmin.

Below is the table structure -

[image: Database table structure]

Comment: Note that you have named `zb_inv_payment_id` as `zb_ipi`. This means that you have to use `zb_ipi` as reference.

Comment: @Dejvid the alias doesn't change anything. Both are returning null. I was just using that for debugging purpose. Also if I use 199 as the id in `where` clause, it works fine. Similarly if I make a new entry(201) and get 200 in the where clause, it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select IPM.collected, IPM.invoice_id, IPM.invoice_payment_id, 
        zb_inv_payment_id
        from expense_system.invoice_payment_mapper as IPM             
        where IPM.invoice_payment_id = 200
```

For `zb_inv_payment_id` column, you have given an alias `zb_ipi` that's the cause of your error. You should use `zb_ipi` or remove it and use `zb_inv_payment_id`

Comment: the alias doesn't change anything. Both are returning null. I was just using that for debugging purpose. Also if I use 199 as the id in `where` clause, it works fine. Similarly if I make a new entry(201) and get 200 in the where clause, it starts working.